# How to add additional rows and text when export excel in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-excel

When export excel in ssrs, it is showing the exact report downloaded in excel. But I need some customisation to add additional rows and text above the downloaded excel, not in original report. Please guide me.
 Not sure this is feasible or not.

This site having some kind of code, but not sure it can work for my need or not.    https://reportsyouneed.com/export-excel-without-making-mess/

Answer (score 1):

Add all the elements you need to your report, the hide the ones you only want showing in Excel by setting the hidden property based on the render format.

So you can do things like

```
=Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive
```

If the above was used as the `Hidden` property expression it would hide an the item if you were viewing in an interactive session.

You can also do this...

```
=NOT(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "Excel")
```

This would show and element only if the report was rendered as Excel.